# QML Image smooth property not working

Tags: qt, qml, antialiasing

In QML I've created a `Rectangle` view with a set of `Image` elements in it. I can't seem to get the `smooth` property to work, which is set to `true` for both the view and the images. I've tried scaling the images themselves and scaling the view. No matter what I do, I get a jagged scaled image. Am I missing something?

I'm working with Qt 5.2 and am using a `QtQuick2ApplicationViewer` (subclass of `QQuickView`) as my main view.

I've found solutions where smoothing is applied by replacing the image handler in the engine, but I feel like the `smooth` property should just work out of the box.

Code:

```
Image {
    source: "image_400x400.png"
    width:  400
    height: 400
    smooth: true

    transform {
        Scale {xScale: 0.25; yScale: 0.25}
    }
}
```

Second attempt:

```
Image {
    source: "image_400x400.png"
    width:  100
    height: 100
    smooth: true
}
```

Third attempt:

```
Rectangle {
    width:  400
    height: 400
    smooth: true

    Image {
        source: "image_400x400.png"
        width:  400
        height: 400
        smooth: true
    }

    transform {
        Scale {xScale: 0.25; yScale: 0.25}
    }
}
```

I get the same result every time.

**Update:** as suggested by Nejat, I tried the new Qt 5 `antialiasing` property. The result does improve, but when scaling below 0.5x edges still get a bit jagged. Is there any way to change the antialiasing quality?

From left to right:

- expected output (scaled with Photoshop, unedited)
- `antialiasing` and `smooth` enabled
- only `smooth` enabled

[image: Three antialiasing results with zoom]

I'm also still wondering why `smooth` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For smooth downsampling you need **mipmaps**!

With Qt 5.3 (which will be released very soon) this will work:

```
Image {
    source: "image_400x400.png"
    width: 100
    height: 100
    mipmap: true
}
```

For Qt 5.2 you can try the following as an higher-quality alternative to your multisampling approach:

```
ShaderEffectSource {
    id: src
    sourceItem: Image { source: "image_400x400.png" }
    mipmap: true
}

ShaderEffect {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    property var source: src
}
```

If you don't need to change the scale of the image dynamically, the optimal approach (for all relevant Qt versions) is this:

```
Image {
    source: "image_400x400.png"
    sourceSize.width: 100
    sourceSize.height: 100
}
```

The image will be high-quality downscaled on the CPU and then uploaded to the GPU.
Be aware that, because image information is lost, it will look worse when shown at the scale of the original image.

**Regarding the `smooth` property:**

The `smooth` property of an `Image` enables linear interpolation. It's **on by default** and it's an improvement over [nearest-neighbor interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation), which is used when `smooth = false`; but it doesn't help much for downscaling.

**Regarding the `antialising` property:**

Setting `antialiasing = true` **doesn't** change the quality of the image scaling at all. It just smoothes the edges, which might be important when the image is rotated.

Comment: This is really elaborate, thank you Kay! I'm messing around with it now - it works, but the out-of-the-box result has so much aliasing its getting blurry when I scale images down more than 4x. I guess writing custom shader effects is the next step? I might just stick to the surface format solution I posted earlier to keep things simple.

Comment: Thanks again Kay, `mipmap: true` indeed solved the issue as of Qt 5.3.

Comment: Thank you! I spent a good fifteen minutes futzing with the `antialias` property wondering why it wasn't doing anything....

Answer (score 2):

You should set the “antialiasing” property to true. It can be set on any item, including the Canvas. From the documentation:

> > Primarily used in Rectangle and image based elements to decide if the
> >     item should use antialiasing or not. Items with antialiasing enabled
> >     require more memory and are potentially slower to render.
>
> The default is false

So it can be like:

```
Image {
    source: "image_400x400.png"
    width:  100
    height: 100
    smooth: true
    antialiasing: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nejat! Seems like `antialiasing` is a new property in Qt 5. It does improve the rendering, but the result is still a bit jagged.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the result from your suggestion. I still feel like the `smooth` property should make a difference (it still does nothing) and I should be able to set antialiasing quality somehow. Any thoughts?

Comment: To make image looks good while stretching , I will suggest you to use svg image instead of png image.

Comment: Using SVG imagery did not make a difference. SVGs seem to be presampled, so when I scale the image the same low quality antialiasing is visible.

Comment: SVG images are vectors. Unlike raster images like PNG, vectors do not lose quality during scaling i think the problem is something else.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** as of Qt 5.3, the `mipmap` property solves the issue. The answer below only applies to Qt 5.2 or older.

Adding the `antialiasing` property (since Qt 5) did what you would expect the `smooth` property to do. Thanks for that, [Nejat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23292482/1854499). However, as posed in the updated question, the antialiasing quality is still bad. To solve this, define a custom surface format to set a custom antialiasing sampling rate (excerpt from `main.cpp`):

```
QtQuick2ApplicationViewer view;

QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setSamples(16);
view.setFormat(format);
```

See the docs: [QSurfaceFormat::setSamples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsurfaceformat.html#setSamples).

Many suggest using SVG instead of PNG. In my experience, at least with the default Qt Quick setup, SVGs get sampled at a certain size and are thus treated the exact same as PNGs.